# Функция не полностью проводит валидацию input

Tags: javascript

Я новенький в js и пытаюсь сейчас сделать задание на валидацию инпутов.
Написал следующий код:

```js
window.onload = function (e) {

    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');
    var submit = document.querySelector('input[type=submit]');
    var errorMsg = 'Form must be filled out';

    submit.onclick = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            if (inputs[i].value == '') {
                inputs[i].classList.add('error'),
                    inputs[i].focus(),
                    console.log(errorMsg);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    };

};
```

```css
html, body{
    margin: 40px;
}

.error {
    outline-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <form>
        Login:
        <input type="text" value="Login"></br>
        E-Mail:
        <input type="text" value="E-mail"></br>
        <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
    </form>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
```

Проблема, в которую я уперся, это непроверяемый второй инпут, т.е. если я заполняю первый, а второй оставляю пустой, то валидатор это игнорирует и разрешает отправить форму. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: А где у вас вторая форма?

Comment: Имел в виду инпут, прошу прощения.

Comment: Вынесите `return true` за пределы цикла, вы попадаете в него после первой успешной проверки

Comment: В блоке `if` я бы использовал `;` вместо `,`

Comment: @br3t Огромное спасибо, вынесение return помогло.